# Can't see the list of new items after importing

Tags: wordpress, import

I found an issue after importing the items. New items cant't be displayed on the list in frontend but they are added to the admin dashboard. Manually updated I can see them on the list.

CMS: Wordpress
Plugins I use: Essential Real Estate, WP All Import.

What I did: I heard about post meta updating and I also saw that it can be a query problem (but the items added manually are displayed and I can't see any problem with it).

The question: how can I see them added right after importing ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of code but I can't see the reason for not displaying items. I import the items and the only old posts creating manually are shown.

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => $custom_property_items_amount,
    'post_type'           => 'property',
    'orderby'   => array(
        'menu_order'=>'ASC',
        'date' =>'DESC',
    ),
    'offset'              => ( max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) - 1 ) * $custom_property_items_amount,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'post_status'         => array('publish','pending','draft','future','private'),

);
$data = new WP_Query( $args );
        <div class="<?php echo join( ' ', $wrapper_classes ) ?>">
            <?php if ( $data->have_posts() ) :
                while ( $data->have_posts() ): $data->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php ere_get_template( 'content-property.php', array(
                        'custom_property_image_size' => $custom_property_image_size,
                        'property_item_class' => $property_item_class
                    )); ?>

                <?php endwhile; 
            else: ?>
                <div class="item-not-found"><?php esc_html_e( 'Not found', 'essential-real-estate' ); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <?php
            $max_num_pages = $data->max_num_pages;
            ere_get_template( 'global/pagination.php', array( 'max_num_pages' => $max_num_pages ) );
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
```